# I need an alternative of Twitterizer for .NET Framework 2

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I have tried to use Twitterizer but it can only be compiled in .NET 3.5 and 4.

I need to update a project that needs to recover the tweets of a user but it is a .NET 2.0 Sharepoint Project.

Do you know any library?

Comment: any full source code sample ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twitter Libraries for .NET

- [Spring.NET Social extension for Twitter](http://www.springframework.net/social-twitter/) by SpringSource – A Spring.NET Social extension with connection support and an API binding for Twitter.
- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/) by Andrew Arnott – an OpenID, OAuth and InfoCard library
- [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock) by Daniel Crena – an HTTP API client supporting OAuth authentication.
- [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) by Joe Mayo – a LINQ provider for the Twitter API
- [OAuth-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/) by Chris – an OAuth library for clients and providers
- [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.com/) by Daniel Crenna & Jason Diller – a Twitter API library built with Hammock
- [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) by DigitallyBorn – a Twitter API library (requires .NET > 3.5)
- [TwitterVB](http://twittervb.codeplex.com/) by Duane Roelands – a VB.NET Twitter API library
- [Budgie](https://bitbucket.org/mabster/budgie) by Matt Hamilton - a very simple library to access Twitter via its HTTP API.
  All methods in the class library are asynchronous, returning Task, so you can await them if you're using C# 5. Budgie is a Portable Class Library supporting .NET 4 (and up) and the Windows Store.

Check this:

[Twitter Libraries .Net](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet)